# Have any planetary systems been found around Population II stars?

Tags: exoplanet, metallicity

I always understood that Population II stars were unlikely to have planets as they were virtually all H and He with very little else.

Have recent observations confirmed this, or have planets been discovered around Population II stars?

Comment: Do you mean [Population III stars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_population#Population_III_stars)? Population II stars do have lower metallicity than Population I, but they are by no means devoid of heavier elements.

Answer (score 4):

[Kapteyn's star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kapteyn%27s_Star) has 14% the metallicity of the Sun and is about 11 billion years old and is in the galactic halo. It has two reported planets.

I don't know if 14% is low enough to count as  Population II, but according to the NASA exoplanet archive it is the lowest metallicity star known to have planets.

Comment: I seem to recall that below $[Fe/H] \approx -0.3$ stars count as Pop II, so that would include Kapteyn's star.

Comment: Its not particularly metal-poor. There is no strict definition, but this would be a borderline case. It is not in the halo, it is only 12 light years from Earth.

Comment: According to the article https://academic.oup.com/mnras/article/350/2/575/1117003 it is a halo star.

Comment: It's kinematically a halo star, but is isn't "in the halo". Pedantic possibly, but a lot of readers would misunderstand. The same reference also provides a lower metallicity than your value.